# doing operator overloading and polymorphism correctly

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, virtual-functions, friend-function

I have two wrapper classes for string and int and one to represent Binary Operation and overloading the operator `<<` to write them in a string format. Unfortunately, I can't overload `<<` without `friend` function and I can't get polymorphism without `virtual` and can't use `friend` with `virtual` !!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class AST {};
class expr: public AST {};

class operator_: public AST {};

class BinOp: public expr {
private:
  expr *_left;
  expr *_right;
  operator_ *_op;
public:
  BinOp(expr *p_left, expr *p_right, operator_ *p_op):_left(p_left),_right(p_right),_op(p_op) {}
  friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const BinOp &binop) {
    out << (binop._left) << " " << (binop._op) << " " << (binop._right);
  }
};

class LShift: public operator_ {
public:
  LShift() {}
  friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const LShift &lshift) {
    out << "<<";
  }
};

class Name: public expr {
private:
  std::string _id;
public:
  Name(std::string p_id) { _id = p_id; }
  friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Name &name) {
    out << name._id;
  }
};

class Num: public expr {
private:
  int n;
public:
  Num(int p_n) { n = p_n; }
  friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Num &num) {
    out << num.n;
  }
};

int main() {

  auto name = Name("x");
  auto num  = Num(5);
  auto lshift = LShift();
  auto binop = BinOp(&name, &num, &lshift);

  std::cout << binop << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

So the program mentioned above outputs the pointer,

```
0x7ffd05935db0 0x7ffd05935d8b 0x7ffd05935d8c
```

but instead of a pointer, I need the objects needed to print.

```
x << 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, having operator overloading an polymorphism in the same class is an indication that you're mixing value-style classes and identity-style classes, and thus a C++-specific code smell.

But I would say that the stream insertion operator is an exception.

The solution is to overload the operator once, and forward to a function that is more amenable to overriding.

```
class AST {
public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& s) const = 0;
  virtual ~AST() {} // you probably want this one too
};

// no need for friendliness
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& s, const AST& node) {
  node.print(s);
  return s;
}
```

And then you put the actual printing logic into the `print` overrides of each class.

But I also feel the need to remark that your `AST` class doesn't seem useful. There is really nothing an operator and a binary expression have in common. It's also conceptually wrong to say that an operator or an expression is an abstract syntax tree. An expression is a *part* of an AST, a single node in the tree. An operator is a part of an expression. The entire tree is something different.

You should have separate hierarchy roots for `operator_` and `expr`. And yes, that probably means you have to do the printing stuff twice. It's worth it.